# Is it possible to run two websocket connections asynhronously or use same variables in two separate sessions in R?

Tags: r, multithreading, asynchronous, websocket

I'm setting up an algorithm in R which involves performing tasks on data that is streamed from a websocket. I have sucessfuly implemented a connection to a websocket (using package https://github.com/rstudio/websocket), but my algorithm does not perform optimal due to linear processing of data received from websocket (some important tasks get delayed because less important ones get triggered before them). As the tasks could easily be divided, I am wondering:

1) whether it would be possible to run two websocket connections simultaneously, providing that there is a single data frame (as a global variable) that gets updated in one instance and is accessible in another?

2) is it possible to check the queue from websocket and prioritize certain tables?

3) I am considering also a solution that includes two separate R sessions, but I am not sure if there is a way to access data that gets updated in real time in another R session? Is there a workaround that does not include saving a table in one and loading it in another?

I have already tried this with async (https://github.com/r-lib/async) without much success and I have also tried 'jobs' pannels in the newer versions of RStudio.

I would be happy to provide some code, but at this point I think that this might be irrelevant, as the question that I have is more or less trying to expand the code rather than fix it. I am also aware that probably Python offers an easier solution, but I would still like to exhaust every option that R offers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to accomplish this by running two separate R instances and connecting them using r sockets.